# How to do user input in a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary which takes user input with space. The dictionary takes input a string and integer.

I tried by giving input by array but don't know how to do user input in two arrays simultaneously with space.

```
Dictionary<string, int> Directory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string[] name = new string[n];
int[] phone_no = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
}
    name[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    phone_no[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Directory.Add(name[i], phone_no[i]);
}
```

I want help for doing user input like:

1.Sam 12345678

2.Harry 25468789

Answer (score 1):

Note that a phone number is not an int, but a string. It may start with a zero, and if you'd parse that to an int, you lose the leading zero (0123456789 becomes 123456789). Also, I'd consider "+31 (0)6-12345678" a valid phone number.

Here's an example that does what you want. It keeps requesting input until the user types 'exit' and updates the name with the phonenumber.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var directory = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Keep requesting inputs
    while (true)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        // provide a possibility to break the loop.
        if (input == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }

        string[] items = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (items.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expecting '{Name} {Phonenumber}'");
            continue;
        }

        directory[items[0]] = items[1];
    }

    // TODO: Do something with directory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line using String.Split()
i.e.

```
var pair = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
Dictionary.Add(pair[0], int.Parse(pair[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> Directory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number of inputs");
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name " + i + 1 + " : ");
            string Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Age " + i + 1 + " : ");
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Directory.Add(Name, Age);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press key to display the contents of your dictionary..");
        Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (var item in Directory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : " + item.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("Age : " + item.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gnWGdo)